# Ajv — Use actual data in a schema

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

```
    field_name: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        min: { type: "number", minimum: 0, maximum: 600 },
        max: { type: "number", minimum: 0, maximum: 600 },
      },
      required: ["min", "max"],
      additionalProperties: false,
    },
```

I am using ajv to validate my objects in node.

For the object above, how do I further specify that `max` must always be greater than `min`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use the data provided for one property in the schema of another but you need to enable [`$data`](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html#data-reference) as an option when creating your Ajv instance:

*note: `$data` is a JSON Pointer*

```js
const ajv = new Ajv({$data: true});

const validate = ajv.compile({
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    min: {
      type: 'number',
      minimum: 0,
      exclusiveMaximum: 600
      // i.e. min >= 0 and min < 600
    },
    max: {
      type: 'number',
      exclusiveMinimum: {$data: "1/min"},
      maximum: 600
      // i.e. max > min and max <= 600
    }
  }
});


const test = (obj) => {
  const res = validate(obj);
  console.log(`{min: ${obj.min}, max: ${obj.max}} -> ${res}`);
  if (!res) console.log(validate.errors);
  return res;
}

test({min:   0, max: 500}); // true
test({min: 500, max:   0}); // false
test({min: 200, max: 200}); // false
test({min: 599, max: 600}); // true
test({min: 600, max: 600}); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/8.11.2/ajv7.bundle.js" integrity="sha512-gopWbU/o40XPlW4g/zJHfBUj1z9LKAWK6ZBFH5xiJHDDRRm8cXBo5UMLYTG5G42Pce8pBaWVNozLmvulanI3uQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
const {ajv7: Ajv} = window;
</script>
```

Comment: Beware that `$data` is not a standard JSON Schema keyword. If you only need to evaluate your schema using ajv, you will be fine, but it won't be interoperable between JSON Schema implementations.